# Twilio voice callback

Tags: twilio, voip, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I'm having a tough time getting the Twilio Voice callback function to work properly, and would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this.

I have a working VOIP webapp using Python, twilio package and twilio voice SDK.

I need to get call status when a call is being made: `answered, completed, ringing, in-progress` and the likes.

```
is_record = fetch_recording_data_from_DB
handle_url = '/handle'
callback_url = '/events'
events = 'answered ringing initiated completed'

#incoming call 
dial = Dial(timeout=15, record='record-from-ringing' if is_record else 'false', action=handle_url)
        dial.client(
                identity=contact_data['company_id'] or company_id,
                status_callback_event = events,
                status_callback = callback_url,
                status_callback_method = 'POST'
            )

        return response.append(dial)
```

The `handle_url` is triggered after call ends or the 20s is exhausted with no answer to determine whether to make a call forwarding or play VM, this works fine. No error whatsoever, calls come in - I answer and talk for a while, if I don't, it goes to voicemail, records and hangs up. I see my recording, cost, duration and other data on the calls tab on Twilio console, under Monitor. All fine. I just can't get the status callback bit.

```
#status callback function
def stat_events():
    return request.values, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
```

.....

```
class StatEvents(Resource):
    def post(self):
        return stat_events()
```

Now, on the Twilio console, I can see the response and the other information (fromstate, sequencenumber,...) under Request Inspector (multiple times, as it should be) `xdxxdxd.ngrok.io/events` `(POST, 200)` regarding the call, but on my network tab (chrome) (when I make a call on the frontend) I check under the events network and see `{}` - empty

I tried console.log() on the events, nothing! so either I am not using this option well or there's something magical at play.

I need the status so I can save the call log to my DB (background task) when it's `completed` or `no-answer`.

data I want but it's only showing up on Twilio console and empty on network tab (apart from saving call log, I need this data to show the status on the front-end):

````
    "Called": "+653xxxxxx",
    "ParentCallSid": "CAd1ed07xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ToState": "",
    "CallerCountry": "US",
    "Direction": "outbound-dial",
    "Timestamp": "Fri, 22 Jul 2022 08:58:56 +0000",
    "CallbackSource": "call-progress-events",
    "CallerState": "MI",
    "ToZip": "",
    "SequenceNumber": "0",
    "CallSid": "CA3a39c6b1xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "To": "+653xxxxxxxx",
    "CallerZip": "",
    "ToCountry": "SG",
    "CalledZip": "",
    "ApiVersion": "2010-04-01",
    "CalledCity": "",
    "CallStatus": "initiated",
    "From": "+194xxxxxxx",
    "AccountSid": "ACb9f4fe8f52xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "CalledCountry": "SG",
    "CallerCity": "",
    "ToCity": "",
    "FromCountry": "US",
    "Caller": "+1947xxxxxx",
    "FromCity": "",
    "CalledState": "",
    "FromZip": "",
    "FromState": "MI"
}```

```handle_url```'s function uses ```DialCallStatus``` in place of ```CallStatus```, as I read that this would be sent by Twilio request to the endpoint.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You describe that you are receiving requests to your `/events` webhook, but that you're not getting events in the browser.

When you register to receive events via a `status_callback_url` then those events are only sent as webhooks to your server.

However, if you have implemented the Twilio Voice SDK in JavaScript, then you can get call events by listening to events on the [`Twilio.Device` object](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliodevice#events) and on [`Twilio.Call` objects](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliocall#events). For example, the `Twilio.Device` will emit the [`incoming`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliodevice#incoming-event) event when there is a new incoming call. And the `Twilio.Call` will emit [`accept`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliocall#accept-event) events when an incoming call is accepted, and [`disconnect`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliocall#disconnect-event) for when a call is over.

You can use these events to show call progress in your UI.

Comment: Thanks, @philnash.
So in other to return call status on that ```/events``` to view on network tab, I should just do: ```return request.values.get('DialCallStatus'), {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}```? I'll give that a try then.

I would have gone with the option of getting this data from Twilio.Device and Twilio.Call, but I need to extract call data and store in my DB, data points like duration, price, recording_url, and the likes, since it's much straightforwarding doing:

```if call_status == 'completed':
    info = Client.calls(sid).fetch()
    #save_to_db(info)
```

Comment: If you are talking about the network tab in your browser, then you will not see the webhook requests from Twilio to your server in the browser. But, if you are storing the data in the database, then you don't need to see it in the browser's network tab, you just need to receive the call on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Events looks to be a list:

status_callback_event=['initiated', 'answered']

Comment: Thanks @Alan, I thought the rest api accepted the events in a list datatype, where as DIAL string?